# cannot access a disposed object when opening external exe file from my application

Tags: .net, vb.net, objectdisposedexception

I've a problem with an application i have to use at work. That application is in .net (created by my company). 
The application call some object that are .exe file. When i try to open it i received the following error:

```
cannot access a disposed object
```

I know that it's not really revelant but i've got that problem on my pc and my collegue that use the same application doesn't received that error.

I've already check their configuration and i've the same than us. I supposed there are some problems of compatibilty with the framework or thing like that.

Could you have an idea?

Stacktrace

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object named "Form".
Object name: "Form".
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at OSP.ScriptEditor.Model.OSPState.ShowUI_Exe(Boolean autoOK) in d:\documents and settings\slan\my documents\visual studio projects\script editor\model\ospstate.cs:line 1851
   at OSP.ScriptEditor.Model.OSPState.ShowUI(Boolean autoOK) in d:\documents and settings\slan\my documents\visual studio projects\script editor\model\ospstate.cs:line 1980
   at OSP.ScriptEditor.Model.OSPState.ModifyCompo() in d:\documents and settings\slan\my documents\visual studio projects\script editor\model\ospstate.cs:line 996


************** Operating System **************

Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 3  -  English (United States)
Current Culture: French (Belgium)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************

mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/microsoft.net/framework/v1.1.4322/mscorlib.dll
    Last Modified on: 25/12/2011 10:06:44
----------------------------------------
ScriptEditor24
    Assembly Version: 2.4.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/ScriptEditor24.exe
    Last Modified on: 24/05/2006 9:39:06
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system/1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089/system.dll
    Last Modified on: 6/06/2012 16:36:11
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.windows.forms/1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089/system.windows.forms.dll
    Last Modified on: 6/06/2012 16:36:11
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.DataInter
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/AxInterop.DataInter.DLL
    Last Modified on: 7/02/2003 19:27:22
----------------------------------------
OSP.ScriptEditor
    Assembly Version: 2.4.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/OSP.ScriptEditor.DLL
    Last Modified on: 24/05/2006 9:39:02
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.drawing/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/system.drawing.dll
    Last Modified on: 6/06/2012 16:36:39
----------------------------------------
Interop.DataInter
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/Interop.DataInter.DLL
    Last Modified on: 7/02/2003 19:27:22
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.management/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/system.management.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:21:59
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.data/1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089/system.data.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:21:59
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.xml/1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089/system.xml.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:21:59
----------------------------------------
OSP.Shared
    Assembly Version: 2.4.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/OSP.Shared.DLL
    Last Modified on: 8/05/2006 10:06:26
----------------------------------------
Syncfusion.Shared.Base
    Assembly Version: 3.201.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/syncfusion.shared.base/3.201.1.0__3d67ed1f87d44c89/syncfusion.shared.base.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:21
----------------------------------------
Syncfusion.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.201.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/syncfusion.core/3.201.1.0__632609b4d040f6b4/syncfusion.core.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:19
----------------------------------------
Syncfusion.Tools.Windows
    Assembly Version: 3.201.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/syncfusion.tools.windows/3.201.1.0__3d67ed1f87d44c89/syncfusion.tools.windows.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:28
----------------------------------------
Northwoods.Go
    Assembly Version: 2.2.1.1
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/northwoods.go/2.2.1.1__a4e3b7b70161cfe8/northwoods.go.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:18
----------------------------------------
System.DirectoryServices
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.directoryservices/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/system.directoryservices.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:22:00
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:21:58
----------------------------------------
Syncfusion.Grid.Windows
    Assembly Version: 3.201.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/syncfusion.grid.windows/3.201.1.0__3d67ed1f87d44c89/syncfusion.grid.windows.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:24
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.SHDocVw
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/AxInterop.SHDocVw.DLL
    Last Modified on: 29/09/2004 20:47:04
----------------------------------------
Interop.SHDocVw
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/Interop.SHDocVw.DLL
    Last Modified on: 29/09/2004 20:47:04
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/accessibility/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/accessibility.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:20:55
----------------------------------------
Syncfusion.Edit.Windows.Legacy
    Assembly Version: 3.201.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/syncfusion.edit.windows.legacy/3.201.1.0__3d67ed1f87d44c89/syncfusion.edit.windows.legacy.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:20
----------------------------------------
OSP.SibUI
    Assembly Version: 2.4.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/OSP.SibUI.DLL
    Last Modified on: 24/05/2006 9:38:53
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/system.design/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/system.design.dll
    Last Modified on: 9/05/2011 13:21:57
----------------------------------------
dao
    Assembly Version: 10.0.4504.0
    CodeBase: file:///c:/winnt/assembly/gac/dao/10.0.4504.0__31bf3856ad364e35/dao.dll
    Last Modified on: 7/06/2012 16:20:17
----------------------------------------
Interop.VXPLibrary
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/Interop.VXPLibrary.DLL
    Last Modified on: 14/07/2003 22:24:46
----------------------------------------
OSP.Net.SmfServer
    Assembly Version: 2.4.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program Files/Alcatel/OSP/Toolchain/in24/OSP.Net.SmfServer.DLL
    Last Modified on: 24/05/2006 9:38:48
----------------------------------------
```

Regards,

Julein

Comment: Do you have access to the code and/or a stacktrace of the message?

Comment: Stacktrace, kind of yes, code no.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but do you run on a 64 bit environment and your colleague on 32 bit?

Comment: No I'm in 32bit also, but it's maybe due to C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Updates\M2656353.
I'm removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's fixed by removing the KB2656353. It's not really safe but it's work.

Comment: That was a security update for System.Web.dll.  The odds that your answer is accurate and helps anybody ought to be close to zero.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but that was the fix I need to make my program work like a charm. The solution is only personal and it will be better to go through the code to make it better than using a workaround like this.